# Azure Devops Query templates

Tags: azure, templates, azure-devops, export, devops

So I'm very new to Azure Devops, and I have an issue with applying the same exact queries manually for many different projects.

Is there a way to apply an already made query onto another project?

Maybe an export/import kinda thing that I missed?

Maybe a place to write the query in code, so it's easier to copy paste?

Or maybe is there a way to do it with code and interact with the Azure Devops Query api?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

There is extension that allow to import export as files 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor&targetId=e93d04c7-2923-4673-ab1a-38fc97ad5666&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList